# Why doesn't the for loop execute here?

Tags: python, for-loop, text

I expected this code to create the `list_of_rows2 list`, then run the for loop. How come the for loop doesnt get executed? Is this just how `open` works?

```
infile = r"D:\temp.txt"

with open(infile) as file2:

    list_of_rows2 = [x.split() for x in file2]

    for x in file2:
        print x
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do with file..?

Comment: Nothing, I just didn't understand why this didnt work as I expected it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's how `open` works. It returns an iterator to the file object. You can only iterate over it once till exhaustion.

The first iteration in the list comprehension exhausts the file iterator, so that by the time you're going over it again, there's nothing left to iterate over.

This has the advantage of not loading the entire file, which could be sometimes large, all at once into memory, choking your program on memory. However, you can (if you need to) load the file into memory by calling the `readlines` method of the file object:

```
with open(infile) as file2:
    file2 = file2.readlines() # or list(file2)
    list_of_rows2 = [x.split() for x in file2]

    for x in file2:
        print x
```

Another option is to seek the file to its start position by calling `file2.seek(0)`, before iterating over it again.

Comment: You can also reset the iterator by calling `file2.seek(0)` if that's better for your situation.

Comment: @Collin Yes, that's another nice option. How did I miss that.

Comment: Or maybe OP actually meant `for x in list_of_rows:`?